# Как работает ORM?

Tags: oracle, orm, django

У меня есть БД Oracle. Там есть данные. И вот я не понимаю, когда я генерирую Модель В Django или Hibernate. Это все создает как бы копию существующей таблицы, но не синхронизируется с ней - так?
Вопрос вообще про ORM. То - есть создавая классы они синхронизируются с БД(в которой уже есть данные) или создают новую и туда уже мапишь?

Comment: У Вас вопрос по работе Django / Hibernate или вообще про ORM?

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае, ORM - это прокладка между объектным и табличным представлением данных. Как таковая эта прокладка не копирует данные (иначе это привело бы избыточному дублированию данных).

На примере Django. После того, как вы описали модель данных в Django, и провели синхронизацию

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Django ORM выведет структуру базы данных из описания моделей и приведет базу в соответствии с ними. В конечном счете, модель - есть некая "виртуальная" сущность, в то время как таблицы базы - "реальная".

Comment: Это понятно. А вот когда я пишу новое приложение и в базе нет таблиц они создаются ведь так. А когда есть синхронизируются? или как?

Comment: Да именно так. Когда нет - создаются, когда есть синхронизируются. Однако когда вносятся изменения в модели, то, возможно, потребуются и миграции базы данных.

Comment: не совсем верное мнение насчет syncdb,он только создает еще не существующие таблицы в БД, но не изменяет их...

[пруф на доки][1]


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb